# Prevent node.js from reading node_modules besides immediate folder

Tags: node.js

Say I have this situation:

```
node_modules/         
muh_project/
  node_modules/
  index.js
```

say I do this:

```
cd muh_project && node index.js
```

How can I prevent the node.js runtime from reading node_modules anywhere but the immediate node_modules folder? By default, Node.js will walk up the filesystem looking for node_modules until it reaches $HOME. But for a certain use case (*for testing*) I want to prevent that behavior.

The only thing I can think of is something like this:

```
mv_all_node_modules_dirs
node muh_project
mv_all_node_modules_dirs_back_to_original_name
```

The renaming solution seems really bad, is there another way?

Update: An additional constraint - I am running someone else's program with bash, so whatever I change has to be external to their program, either an env variable or changing directory names, or whatever. Modifying require() or whatnot won't work so good.

A newer idea - I could change permissions, so that the program doesn't have permissions to any files below the current dir? Last time I checked *nix can't really do this (which is super lame).

Here is my rename script, so you get the idea:

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
let current = path.dirname(process.cwd());
const home = process.env.HOME;

let renameThisDir = 'node_modules';
let renameTo = 'r2g_nodemodules'

if(process.argv[2] === 'undo'){
    // swap the variables
   [renameTo, renameThisDir] = [renameThisDir, renameTo];
}

while (current.length >= home.length) {

    let nm = path.resolve(current, renameThisDir)
    let renamed = path.resolve(current, renameTo)

    fs.stat(nm, (err, stats) => {

        if (!(stats && stats.isDirectory())) {
            return;
        }

        fs.rename(nm, renamed, err => {
            err && console.error(err.message);
        });
    });

    current = path.join(current, '..');
}
```

Comment: Did you find *"By default, Node.js will walk up the filesystem looking for node_modules until it reaches $HOME. "* documented somewhere?  I have not seen that behavior myself so was wondering where you discovered this?  node.js has a global location that it searches for globally installed modules.  Are you sure that's not what is happening here?

Comment: Perhaps modify the array `require.paths` before calling your `require(...)`.  See this article https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm for info.

Comment: Would https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatten-packages work for you?

Comment: @jfriend00 Read it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#loading_from_node_modules_Folders) search for "file system is reached".

Comment: @jfriend00 I am running someone else's program with bash, so whatever I change has to be external to their program, either an env variable or changing directory names, or whatever

Comment: I have an idea - I could change permissions, so that the program doesn't have permissions to any files below the current dir?

Comment: Well, then please edit your question to state that you have to figure this out external to node.js and the program in question.  That was not stated at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated the question pls let me know if you like better

Comment: Would running it inside a docker container or chroot jail be an option for you?

Comment: I have a Docker solution for this already, just looking for host fs solution, and so yes chroot jail would be neat! pls elaborate or add an answer thx

Comment: @Paul I read about chroot a little bit, just FYI I would need it to work on *nix including MacOS, thx